# Hibernate collection set column as index

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, indexing

I looked into the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed) (hibernate 4.1) . And I'm kind of confuse, I wish to be able to use the annotation `@OrderColumn(name="orders_index")` in my `set Collection` (for design purpose). Right now, I'm actually adding manually a orders_index manually in my `PersonnalTaskMacro` but it's getting a pain in the *** (I need to refactor that...). I came accross the `@MapKeyColumn(name="orders_number")`, but it's not really what I want. How can I achieve this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERS_TASK_MACRO_PARAMETER")
public class PersonnalTaskMacroParameter extends Parameter {

    /* .... */

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERS_TASK_MACRO_JOIN", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MODULE_PARAMETER_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PERS_TASK_MACRO_ID") })
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_PERS_TASK_MACRO_PARAM_ID", inverseName="FK_PERS_TASK_MACRO_ID")
    private Set<PersonnalTaskMacro> personnalTaskMacroSet = new HashSet<PersonnalTaskMacro>();

/* .... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Set is not an ordered collection.  The [documentation you cited](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed) points in the right direction: change

```
Set<PersonnalTaskMacro> personnalTaskMacroSet ...
```

to

```
List<PersonnalTaskMacro> personnalTaskMacros ...
```

You can also use SortedSets to do [something similar](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-sorted), but that depends on the sort key being part of the entity that you have a collection of.

Comment: Happy to help. If you're all set, you should accept the answer, using the green check.